# Why AWS Lambda execution time is long using pg-promise

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-lambda, pg-promise

I started using AWS Lambda to perform a very simple task which is executing an SQL query to retrieve records from an RDS postgres database and create SQS message base on the result.

Because Amazon is only providing `aws-sdk` module (using node 4.3 engine) by default and we need to execute this SQL query, we have to create a custom deployment package which includes `pg-promise`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
console.info('Loading the modules...');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new aws.SQS();
var config = {
  db: {
    username: '[DB_USERNAME]',
    password: '[DB_PASSWORD]',
    host: '[DB_HOST]',
    port: '[DB_PORT]',
    database: '[DB_NAME]'
  }
};

var pgp = require('pg-promise')({});
var cn = `postgres://${config.db.username}:${config.db.password}@${config.db.host}:${config.db.port}/${config.db.database}`;

if (!db) {
  console.info('Connecting to the database...');
  var db = pgp(cn);
} else {
  console.info('Re-use database connection...');
}

console.log('loading the lambda function...');
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

  var now = new Date();
  console.log('Current time: ' + now.toISOString());

  // Select auction that need to updated
  var query = [
    'SELECT *',
    'FROM "users"',
    'WHERE "users"."registrationDate"<=${now}',
    'AND "users"."status"=1',
  ].join(' ');

  console.info('Executing SQL query: ' + query);
  db.many(query, { status: 2, now: now.toISOString() }).then(function(data) {    
    var ids = [];
    data.forEach(function(auction) {
      ids.push(auction.id);
    });

    if (ids.length == 0) {
      callback(null, 'No user to update');

    } else {

      var sqsMessage = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify({ action: 'USERS_UPDATE', data: ids}), /* required */
        QueueUrl: '[SQS_USER_QUEUE]', /* required */
      };

      console.log('Sending SQS Message...', sqsMessage);
      sqs.sendMessage(sqsMessage, function(err, sqsResponse) {

        console.info('SQS message sent!');
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        } else {
          callback(null, ids.length + ' users were affected. SQS Message created:' + sqsResponse.MessageId);
        }
      });
    }

  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });

};
```

When testing my lambda function, if you look at the WatchLogs, the function itself took around 500ms to run but it says that it actually took 30502.48 ms (cf. screenshots).

[image]
[image]

So I'm guessing it's taking 30 seconds to unzip my 318KB package and start executing it? That for me is just a joke or am I missing something? I tried to upload the zip and also upload my package to S3  to check if it was faster but I still have the same latency.

I noticed that the Python version can natively perform SQL request without any custom packaging...

All our applications are written in node so I don't really want to move away from it, however I have a hard time to understand why Amazon is not providing basic npm modules for database interactions.

Any comments or help are welcome. At this point I'm not sure Lambda would be benefic for us if it takes 30 seconds to run a script that is triggered every minute...

Anyone facing the same problem?

---

**UPDATE**: This is how you need to close the connection as soon as you don't need it anymore (thanks again to Vitaly for his help):

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

  [...]

  db.many(query, { status: 2, now: now.toISOString() }).then(function(data) {    

    pgp.end(); // <-- This is important to close the connection directly after the request

    [...]
```

Comment: Try adding more logging to pinpoint where the 30 seconds comes from, whether it's the query itself or something you do afterward.  There's not enough information in what you've posted to pinpoint.  And AWS tends to make the runtime environment for each language it supports the language's "standard" (plus the AWS SDK).  Python may consider SQL standard whereas JavaScript does not.

Comment: Probably relevant to set expectations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html#topic3

Comment: I have logs at the beginning (first line "connecting to the database") and at the end (cf. cloudwatch screenshot) so I know that the execution time of MY code is ~500ms give or take. It doesn't explain the 30 other seconds that are billed. Also reading the docs you provided, it doesn't explain what is exactly happening during this 30 seconds. Is it the time to unzip? to create the container?

Comment: By any chance you are measuring how long the application runs versus how long the query takes to execute? If it is the first one, then your query executes and returns fast, and you are sitting idle, waiting for the database connection pool to expire and close itself, as per parameter [poolIdleTimeout](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L44).

Comment: yeah, you were right. I tried a couple more custom functions, some without queries, and one with a simple query and it's always taking 30 seconds. So I looked up pg-promise doc and found this: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#library-de-initialization and it says `[...] make sure that the process terminates without any delay. If you do not call it, your process may be waiting for 30 seconds (default) [...] If, however you normally exit your application by killing the NodeJS process, then you don't need to use it.` So apparently lambda is not killing the node process.

Comment: If you add the answer @vitaly-t I'll approve it ;)

Comment: @maxwell2022 see also [the examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/examples), they all do it ;)

Comment: Amazon shouldn't provide npm modules, even commonly used ones, to avoid breaking customer functions when updating APIs.  Customer functions should bundle all dependencies (including AWS SDK, even though it's provided) to ensure that updates don't cause undesired behavior changes.

Comment: I Agree with you @JeffLearman, I think I was just pissed that I could not manage to find the issue ;) It would be awesome if Lambda could run docker commands within custom containers... but hey... I think I'm asking for too much here :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution time should be measured based on the length of operations being executed, as opposed to how long it takes for the application to exit.

There are many libraries out there that make use of a connection pool in one form or another. Those typically terminate after a configurable period of inactivity.

In case of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which in turn uses [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), such period of inactivity is determined by parameter [poolIdleTimeout](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L44), which defaults to 30 seconds. With [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) you can access it via `pgp.pg.defaults.poolIdleTimeout`.

If you want your process to exit after the last query has been executed, you need to shut down the connection pool, by calling `pgp.end()`. See chapter [Library de-initialization](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#library-de-initialization) for details.

It is also shown in most of the [code examples](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/examples), as those need to exit right after finishing.